"fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found." when generating apk with buildozer
I am trying to make an app of a simple game I created in python/pygame, I followed the instructions from https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#targeting-android to install buildozer, but when I run buildozer -v android debug in the linux terminal an error occurs after about 20 minutes that distrupts the process. I am running linux on windows 10 using wsl.
I am using:
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
python 3.8.10
buildozer 1.5.0

The error that occurs:
/home/ubun/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -I/mnt/c/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -DANDROID -I/home/ubun/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/mnt/c/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/armeabi-v7a/include/python3.1 -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -DSDL2 -I/mnt/c/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni/SDL/include -Isrc_c -I/mnt/c/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include -I/mnt/c/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build -c src_c/_sdl2/sdl2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/src_c/_sdl2/sdl2.o
src_c/_sdl2/sdl2.c:211:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
  #include "longintrepr.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

---
For help with compilation see:
    https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Compilation
To contribute to pygame development see:
    https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
---

error: command '/home/ubun/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1


  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,pygame,jnius,sdl2,sdl2_image,sdl2_mixer,sdl2_ttf,png,jpeg', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/mnt/c/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'
#     NAME = 'MainComputer'
#     PWD = '/mnt/c/test'
#     LOGNAME = 'ubun'
#     MOTD_SHOWN = 'update-motd'
#     HOME = '/home/ubun'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/52_interop'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'ubun'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/ubun/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.424.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/VMware/VMware Player/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common '
 'Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common '
 'Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Java/jdk-17.0.1/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL '
 'Server/160/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL '
 'Server/160/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client '
 'SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL '
 'Server/160/DTS/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL '
 'Server/160/DTS/Binn/:/mnt/c/Users/Sync/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/Sync/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/:/mnt/c/Users/Sync/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/Sync/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft '
 'VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/yt dl:/snap/bin:/home/ubun/.local/bin/')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/ubun'
#     _ = '/home/ubun/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/ubun/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/ubun/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/ubun/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

I tried to run it from different versions of Ubuntu and wsl but to no avail so far, i suspect that something is wrong with the python code of buildozer or with some of its dependencies, but I just couldn't figure it out, I would like to get some help.
